# Additional openings that are Chess Position Trainer compatible

Tags: opening, software, database, beginner

I just started playing with Chess Position Trainer and I really enjoy the experience of playing through the "Closed Sicilian” repetoir that comes pre-loaded.  The manual mentions that you can build your own or purchase some through ebooks.

Where can I get additional openings that are Chess Position Trainer compatible and are targeted for beginners 1300?

The manual states:

> After importing a professional ebook you can use the function Re-ordering of Candidate Moves
>   (p. 77). This will take care of positions where the author offers alternative moves for a position. 
>   It only works if the author used move assessments for each alternative though (which is usually 
>   the case). Then the program will automatically bring them in order!

Comment: In my opinion it's hard to get downloadable repertoires for chess position trainer in its own format for free, but I'm not sure, maybe you can somehow manipulate other pgn files and make it as a CPT repertoire file. Anyway, Here I'm telling you about how you can build your own repertoire. You can visit database.chessbase.com which contains numerous games from great players. Here you can check out any openings you want and can get to know which moves are mostly played and you add those to your CPT repertoire and start building it.

Comment: This question is a duplicate http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/chess-position-trainer

Answer (score 2):

Chess Position Trainer can be loaded with a PGN file of games in your repertoire. The manual describes how to do this.

The question of how to choose a repertoire is dealt with elsewhere on Chess.StackExchange.com.

Good guidance for how to prepare the PGN file for CPT is in the manual.  The manual is available at the Chess Position Trainer website for free.

Answer (score 0):

Found 1 repertoire for Juniors so far:

- http://exeterchessclub.org.uk/content/chess-position-trainer

Also, I've had some luck downloading PGN files from

- http://www.ficsgames.org/

I seem to have found some additional older files here:

- http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/support?view=faq&catid=4&tmpl=component&faqid=22