# Chess Position Trainer

Tags: engines

1. Would anyone know how to set up training in a "random position" with Chess Position Trainer (ver 5.04)?  I know and use its option to train "the variation", but was hoping there would be sort of - "make a move from a randomly chosen position" type of training.
2. Is there a way to set up a position (middlegame, or an endgame) with Chess Position Trainer without having to go over the whole game?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Chess Position Trainer, but [Chesshero](http://innokuo.altervista.org/chesshero.html) has these capabilities you are looking for. You can do the following:

a) Define the pgns from which to pick the random positions

b) Define the start and end move numbers to pick from (this can be useful for generating middle-game or end-game or opening positions specifically)

c) You can define a blunder threshold, which will be used to give you scores when the move you made is evaluated against an engine

d) You can make it timed as well.

Comment: Thanks Keshav.  I am just not sure if Chesshero is as user friendly as Chess Position Trainer is.  If I need to load actual pgn files, that sounds like not exactly what I wanted to use.  I see that it is a free product - maybe I will give it a try.  thanks again....